# Why can't I download MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource sources and find javadocs with Maven?

Tags: maven, repository, javadoc, mysql-connector

I see that for some jars Maven (m2e) automatically downloads sources and/or javadocs. But not for `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` class in `mysql-connector-java` ver. 5.1.18.

Why?

Is this my mistake or sources and docs are not on repository? How to check artifact has no sources using http://search.maven.org/ website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sources are not delivered into Maven Central by the vendor. I assume MySQL does not like to put the sources of their driver onto Maven Central.
Checking for sources is simple, cause there must be a package called mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-sources.jar which is not there.